# Single SQL query on many to many relationship

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a simple database with few tables (and some sample columns):

**Posts** (ID, Title, Content)

**Categories** (ID, Title)

**PostCategories** (ID, ID_Post, ID_Category)

Is there a way to create single SQL query which will return posts with categories that are assigned to each post?

Comment: Thx for answers. I'm using MySQL. To be clear what I mean is that if there are 3 records in Categories, 1 record in Posts and 3 records in PostCategories (so that one post belongs to three categories), then the query should return only one row containing the post, but for example in one of its columns will be those categories where it belongs. In OOP it will be something like one instance of post object containing properties for ID, Title, Content and (generic) list of categories.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
select p.*, group_concat(DISTINCT c.title ORDER BY c.title DESC SEPARATOR ', ')
from Posts p
inner join PostCategories pc on p.ID = pc.ID_Post
inner join Categories c on pc.ID_Category = c.ID
group by p.id, p.title, p.content
```

Comment: Note that this will work with current versions of mysql, but not necessarily with other database systems.

Comment: I love the inner join with `GROUP_CONCAT` more. Since this will not give you multiple results of the posts (if you have more than 1 category), but rather an array of categories for each post. I would still advice this field to give it a name, like so: `group_concat(DISTINCT c.category_name ORDER BY c.category_name DESC SEPARATOR ', ') as categories`

Comment: Also I think `JSON_ARRAYAGG` would be even cooler instead of `GROUP_CONCAT`

Answer (score 19):

Simple joins work well.

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, categories.id, categories.title
FROM posts
JOIN posts_categories ON posts.id = posts_categories.post_id
JOIN categories ON posts_categories.category_id = categories.id
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select p.*, c.*
from Posts p
inner join PostCategories pc on p.ID = pc.ID_Post
inner join Categories c on pc.ID_Category = c.ID
```

If you mean with only one record per post, I will need to know what database platform you are using.

Comment: from posts p => why you added this p ?

Comment: @HossamMaher See https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  If I understand your question correctly, it should be as simple as

```
SELECT Posts.title, Categories.title 
FROM Posts, Categories, PostCategories 
WHERE PostCategories.ID_Post = Posts.ID AND PostCategories.ID_Category = Categories.ID 
ORDER BY Posts.title, Categories.title;
```

Getting one row per Post will be a little more complicated, and will depend on what RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this query also.

```
select e.*,c.* from Posts e, Categories c, PostCategories cp where cp.id in ( select s.id from PostCategories s where s.empid=e.id and s.companyid=c.id );
```